# Date + X days as default value for a column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 columns, import_date and expire_date

So on the import date the default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, is there a way that I can set the value for column 'expire_date' `default (define) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2 days`, or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 48 hours`?

I am using MariaDB

Alternatively I could get the current timestamp in php, add 2 days and update the column on import. But if possible I would prefer to set a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by using DATE_ADD function.

It is difficult to set default timestamp. you use trigger to complete this task.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   UPDATE yourtable SET expire_date=DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL 2 DAY);

END;
```

Comment: No!  That updates every row in the table!  You wanted just `SET NEW.expire_date = OLD.import_date + INTERVAL 14 DAY;`